# What application layer am I missing?

Tags: design-patterns, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I'm trying to figure out the best way to complete the setup of a MVVM application I'm working on.  Right now the architecture has a few peices, but I feel as if something is missing.

Basically, we have a concept of Providers.  Each provider is essentially a gateway to some way to aggregate data into the application.  There is currently three providers, with the potential of getting more.  How we get the data from each provider can be different, so I'm going to outline what we did below.

Basically the process flow is as follows.

```
    User makes request -> 
    Request is sent to a function inside the "Model" -> 
    Function fowards request to a "Processor" which then sends the request to a specific or all "Provider" -> 
    Provider gets the data and returns the requests to the "Processor" -> 
    Processor formats the data so it can be consumed by the model ->
    Model consumes the data and by some binding is displayed back to the user.
```

I feel like the functions inside the model need to be split out into thier own layer.  Normally, I would think a Factory pattern would fit, however, I just don't see that as a beneficial pattern to use.

Then I though about using a Repository pattern, however, again, I don't think that'll work out to what I want, as it's main benefit is for ORM type data access.  However, the concept of using a Repository pattern seems nice, as one place to invoke functionality would work pretty good.

So, with that being said, what else should I do.  Is having the functions inside the Model to populate itself a good or bad thing (It sound very odd to me)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start with a simple existing 
MVVM framework like Galasoft MVVMLight

Spending few hours to study this kind of framework will bring you a lot of answer and show you some common problems with the MVVM pattern such as Event to Command - how to call a MVVM command thru a button click

Btw model should be persistent agnostic, you right thinking to the use of repositories

Comment: We don't have a problem with commanding, or any MVVM elements.  In fact, we're quite happy with the MVVM implementation.  It's the "beyond MVVM" we're trying to digest.

Comment: Ok here what i did : ViewModels contains initializations and calls to repositories methods - and/or web services, my models 'known' nothing about underlying layers. Hope that help.

Comment: Yea, I think that's what I'm going do to.  I found a great article going over the Repository pattern, and it's exactly what I think was missing.  http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article108.aspx probably one of the best articles I've read in a long time.